# Rust: iterating over iter() or vector itself

Tags: loops, rust, iterator

I was watching a Rust lecture and seen I think two ways of iterating over a vector. I could iterate over "vector itself" or over "iter() method". Could you please tell me what is the difference here?

```
fn call(from: &mut Vec<i32>, to: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    for e in from.iter() {
        to.push(*e);
    }
    for e in from {
        to.push(*e);
    }
}

fn printvec(from: & Vec<i32>) {
    for e in from {
        print!("{} ", e);
    }
    println!("");
}

fn main() {
    let mut v1 = vec![1,2,3];
    let mut v2 = vec![1,2,3];
    call(&mut v1, &mut v2);
    printvec(&v1);
    printvec(&v2);
}
```

Comment: all your example use a reference vector so there is none

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Could you please tell me what is the difference here?

Here there is no difference as Stargateur notes. To know what's happening, you simply need to follow the <s>white rabbit</s> trait implementation: Rust's `for` loop "simply" calls [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) on the "RHS". Now if we go down [the list of implementors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#implementors)

#### We can see [an implementation for `&Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#impl-IntoIterator-18)

It's not documented per-se but [looking at the code it just calls `self.iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#2243-2250), so here we do have the confirmation that Stargateur is correct, `&Vec` and `Vec::iter` do the exact same thing

#### [`Vec::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter)

The documentation is a bit terse but it links to [`std::slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) which is "Immutable slice iterator", not necessarily super helpful in and of itself *but* the trait implementation is pretty clear

```rust
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T
}
```

So `Vec<T>::iter` -> `Iter<T>` -> `Iterator<Item=&a>`, meaning when you `.iter()` a vector (or you iterate an `&Vec`) you iterate on *immutable references to the items*. And since `iter` takes `&self` (and `&Vec` is obviously a reference) it also means that the iteration only *borrows* the vector, so once you're done iterating the vector is still there unchanged.

#### `&mut Vec` and `Vec::iter_mut`

Though you didn't mention it that's the second iterator, it's similar to the one above except it yields a [`std::slice::IterMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.IterMut.html) which

```rust
impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T
}
```

so instead of yielding immutable references to items it yields mutable ones, which means you can modify items in-place, e.g. increment them, pretty cool.

#### [`Vec` itself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#impl-IntoIterator-34)

So we come to this, and if you expand the definition you see essentially this:

```rust
impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T> {
    type Item = T
    type IntoIter = IntoIter<T, A>

    pub fn into_iter(self) -> IntoIter<T, A>
```

> Creates a consuming iterator, that is, one that moves each value out of the vector (from start to end). The vector cannot be used after calling this.

Which is pretty self-explanatory: if you iterate on the `Vec` directly it *consumes* the vector, meaning you *will not* be able to use it afterwards.

In return, however, it *moves the ownership* of the vector's items into the iterator, which provides more flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#iterator-loops):

> ```rust
> 'label: for PATTERN in iter_expr {
>     /* loop body */
> }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```rust
> {
>     let result = match IntoIterator::into_iter(iter_expr) {
>         mut iter => 'label: loop {
>             let mut next;
>             match Iterator::next(&mut iter) {
>                 Option::Some(val) => next = val,
>                 Option::None => break,
>             };
>             let PATTERN = next;
>             let () = { /* loop body */ };
>         },
>     };
>     result
> }
> ```

The difference between your for loops is that in one the `iter_expr` is `from` and in the other it is `from.iter()`. `IntoIterator` is implemented like this for a vector reference:

```rust
impl<'a, T, A: Allocator> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T, A> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = slice::Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> slice::Iter<'a, T> {
        self.iter()
    }
}
```

Note that it's calling `self.iter()`, so there is no difference between this iterator and the one you get from your `from.iter()` for loop.