# What is the difference between these two methods of iterating over a vector in Rust?

Tags: rust

What's the difference between the following two methods of iterating over a vector?

```
let names = vec!["Bob", "Frank", "Ferris"];

for name in names.iter() {
    println!("Hello {}", name);
}
```

```
let names = vec!["Bob", "Frank", "Ferris"];

for name in &names {
    println!("Hello {}", name);
}
```

Both of them appear to produce the same behavior. What am I missing?

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66908520/rust-iterating-over-iter-or-vector-itself) because they ask the difference between iterating over `names` vs. `names.iter()`. If it is a duplicate question, why do I need an `&` before `names` in order to not get the following error?

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `names`
  --> src/main.rs:15:17
   |
2  |     let names = vec!["Bob", "Frank", "Ferris"];
   |         ----- move occurs because `names` has type `Vec<&str>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
12 |     for name in names {
   |                 ----- `names` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
...
15 |     for name in names.iter() {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
   |
note: `into_iter` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `names`
  --> /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/iter/traits/collect.rs:262:18
   = note: borrow occurs due to deref coercion to `[&str]`
help: consider iterating over a slice of the `Vec<&str>`'s content to avoid moving into the `for` loop
   |
12 |     for name in &names {
   |                 +

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the linked question. I you get this error, then you must use `names` somewhere else after for loop.

Comment: It's because `for` calls `into_iter()` which for a reference is roughly equivalent to `x.iter().into_iter()`, otherwise you get `names.into_iter()` which returns the elements themselves, not references, hence a move.

Comment: In the linked question, `from` (which is being iterated over) was already a reference, so there was no need to add `&`. In your question `names` is a `Vec` (not `&Vec`) so you need to add `&` to avoid a move and get the same behavior as the linked question.

Comment: While strictly speaking the question you link to is a bit different its top answer covers your question in full, including the difference between iterating on the vector itself and iterating on `&Vec` or `Vec::iter`. The issue you have also has nothing to do with iterating on `&Vec` versus `Vec::iter`, as (as the answer explains) they're the exact same thing.

Comment: @tadman `for` calls `into_iter()` on a `&Vec`, and the [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%26'a+Vec%3CT,+A%3E) of that returns a `slice::Iter`, which yields references to the elements of the `Vec`. (In other words `&Vec` is “just” another `IntoIterator`.) In fact, `vec.iter()` is defined, via `Deref<Target=[T]>`, to just be `slice::Iter(vec)`.

Comment: @BallpointBen I found the behaviour of `for` to be very confusing at first, but the ability to easily pick if you want to iterate references or actual elements directly with a single character of notation is pretty nice! Being able to implement `IntoIter` on other "iterable" things is also a great way to make them `for` compatible, among other things. Rust makes this all fit together so nicely.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I now see that the example is identical to the one in the linked question.